# which is better to do unit testing in hadoop of the 2 repos below?

Tags: unit-testing, hadoop

do you have any experience on using 
https://github.com/jetoile/hadoop-unit
and
https://github.com/sakserv/hadoop-mini-clusters
I am working on some code using `sakserv` repo but I see the `jetoile` is more new and more active
do you know which one is the way to use now 
I just need to simulate a cluster with basic hadoop and spark - nothing fancy

Comment: Hadoop already includes an embedded cluster for testing, which I'm sure Spark itself uses for tests

Comment: so why jetoile is there?

Answer (score 1):

I havent used hadoop-unit.... but I have used hadoop-miniclusters and its pretty neat for unit tests as well as integration tests.

I have modeled our test suite in a way where the resource files from test/resources are copied into the mini cluster in junit setup stage ... and is then available for unit/integration testing

This one is apache owned.
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-minicluster/2.7.1